# Ambiguity definitions - accumulationpoint

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

The literature is a bit ambiguous in my point of view. Limit points and accumulation points seems to be the same. I can accept that; that's just two names for the same. But I've seen different definitions of accumulation points.

**Definition 1:** Let $A\subset X$ be a metric space. A point $a\in A$ is called an accumulation point of $A$ if there exists a sequence $(x_{n})\in A$ such that $x_{n}\in B_{\frac{1}{n}}(a)$, and hence $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_{n}=a$.

**Definition 2:** Let $A$ be a metric space. A point $a\in A$ is called an accumulation point for a sequence $(x_{n})$ if for every $\epsilon >0$ there exists some $x_{n}\neq a$ such that $x_{n}\in B_{\epsilon}(a)$.

**Definition 3:** A point $a$ is called an accumulation point of the set $A$ if every neighborhood of $a$ contains a point $q\neq a$ such that $q\in A$.

So first of all. Do we distinguish accumulation points for sets, from accumulation points for sequences, and are these definitions equivalent ?

Comment: You appear to have written the definition 1 incorrectly as every point in $A$ trivially satisfies that property. For definition 2, did you mean for $A$ to have some inherent metric/topology? Otherwise, what do you mean by 'neighbourhood'?

Comment: Definition 1 is now edited, such that the set $A$ is a subset of the whole space. I think neighbourhood is the term that is used, when dealing with $\mathbb{R}$. It should have been an open ball maybe.

Answer (score 2):

The thing is that, depending in the book one is referring, the definitions, as such change. It is just a matter of convention. Basically there are 2 points worth talking about, the limit point and say the accumulation point.

Define limit point of a set *A* as: 
Let X be a topological space, then $a\in X$ is a limit point of *A* if intersection of every open set, containing a, with *A* is non-empty, that is, given any open set *U*, such that $a\in U$, there exists a point of *A* in *U*.

Define accumulation point of a set *A* as:
Let X be a topological space, then $a\in X$ is an accumulation point of *A* if, given an open set *U*, such that $a\in U$, then there exists a point of *A* in *U*, **other than a**.

The difference is just the last part - **other than a**.

So your Definition 1 is that of a limit point, while Definition 2 and 3 are that of accumulation point.

Note that every accumulation point is a limit point. But every limit point need not be an accumulation point. 
For example, take $\Bbb R$ with the discrete topology, that is every subset of $\Bbb R$ is an open set. Consider the singleton set *A*={0}. 0 is a limit point of *A* but it is not an accumulation point. Rather there does not exist any accumulation point of *A*.

As for the sequence, we talk about limit points and accumulation points of a sequence by just considering the set *A* as the set of all the points of the sequence. And it is interchangeable, in the sense that given a set *A* and its limit and accumulation points, one can construct a sequence with the same limit or accumulation point. The limit point of a sequence is the point of convergence of the sequence.

Essentially there is but a small difference. And so far for me the use of accumulation point has been very little.

Hope this helps.